# Refactor byte array into ENUM values

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a function that receives some data I have to respond with a HEX value.

```
public byte[] GetData(string value) 
{
   byte[] returnVal = null;

    switch(value){
       case "demo1":

            byte byte1 = (byte)((32769 & 0x000000FF));
            byte byte2 = (byte)((32769 & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
            returnVal  = new byte[] { byte1, byte2 };

            break;
       .....
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

In this example I have to response with `0x8001`

I create the following code to build manually a 2 byte array with the right response.

```
  byte byte1 = (byte)((32769 & 0x000000FF));
  byte byte2 = (byte)((32769 & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
  var resCmd = new byte[] { byte1, byte2 };
```

The response can be different depending on the value I received so I want to have a `ENUM` with the responses and then convert that to byte array.

For example:

```
public enum Commands
{
    CMD1 = 0x8001,
    CMD2 = 0x8002,
    CMD3 = 0x8003
};
```

> How can I convert an Enum for example `CMD1` to the 2 byte array that I need?

Thanks

Comment: I added the function, but the question is not about that function is about how to return the ENUM into a 2 Byte[]

Comment: Sorry, but the problem, for me, is, you don't show how you expect the enum to be used/aligned. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: Anyway the function that I referenced in my text is added :) so the post if more complete

Comment: yea.. not just you @ChiefTwoPencils .. it took a second for me to eval 0x8001 to 32769 and determine it's usage there.

Comment: note that you can define your `enum` as `public enum Commands : ushort { ... }` but it doesn't seem to help with implicit usages like the `BitConvertor.GetBytes(...)` in the provided answer - you'll still need explicit casting... not sure at the moment what the significance of defining a type of an enum is.

Comment: sorry if my inquiry is out of place as a comment to your question, but it seems the enum type, or underlying type, is used for determining storage: "The underlying type specifies how much storage is allocated for each enumerator" [cite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum).. had to follow up here since I raised the consideration as it may have been a consideration to an answer here.. but it isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use BitConverter after casting it to a 16 bit unsigned int:

```
    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16)Commands.CMD1);
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `ushort`, but same difference :P

Comment: actually.. you should include the casting of the 2 byte array to Commands here as well.. since the title seems to reflect that: using the provided code snippet, it would be `var resCmd = (Commands)BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { byte1, byte2 }, 0)`.. same concept, just reversed